# MySQL after update trigger using CONCAT_WS: Why is it inserting a newline where I DON'T want it?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

The intended result is to store the notes of edits to a field, in another field.
I want the new notes to APPEND to the storage field, and since the is not function that does this I am attmpting to find a way to work this out without adding more layers of code like functions and stored procedures.

```
/* Before Update Trigger */

DECLARE v_description VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE v_permnotes MEDIUMTEXT;
DECLARE v_oldnote VARCHAR(500);
DECLARE v_now VARCHAR(25);

SET v_now = TRIM(DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d %k:%i:%s'));

SET v_oldnote = OLD.notes;

IF (NEW.permanent_notes IS NULL) THEN
  SET v_permnotes = '';
ELSE
  SET v_permnotes = OLD.permanent_notes;
END IF;

SET NEW.permanent_notes = CONCAT_WS(CHAR(10), v_permnotes, v_now,": ", v_description);
```

I'm aiming to have the results in the permanent field look like this

```
<datetime value>: Some annotation from the notes field.
<a different datetime>: A new annotation
etc....
```

What I get from my current trigger:

```
2018-12-30 17:15:50
: 
Test 17: Start from scratch. 
2018-12-30 17:35:51
: 
Test 18: Used DATE_FORMAT to sxet the time 
2018-12-30 17:45:52
: 
Test 19. Still doing a carriage return after date and after ':'
```

I can't figure out why there is a newline after the date, and then again after the ':'.

If I leave out CHAR(10), I get:

```
Test 17: Start from scratch. 
2018-12-30 17:35:51
: 
Test 18: Used DATE_FORMAT to sxet the time 
2018-12-30 17:45:52
: 
Test 19. Still doing a carriage return after date and after ':'Test 20. Still doing a carriage return after date and after ':'
```

Some fresh/more experienced eyes would be really helpful in debugging this.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact output you really want?

Comment: I indicated the desired output in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just be using plain `CONCAT` here:

```
DECLARE separator VARCHAR(1);

IF (NEW.permanent_notes IS NULL) THEN
    SET separator = '';
ELSE
   SET separator = CHAR(10)
END IF;

-- the rest of your code as is

SET
    NEW.permanent_notes = CONCAT(v_permnotes, separator, v_now, ": ", v_description);
```

The logic here is that we conditionally print a newline (`CHAR(10)`) *before* each new log line, so long as that line is not the very first.  You don't really want `CONCAT_WS` here, which is mainly for adding a separator in between multiple terms.  You only want a single newline in between each logging statement.

Comment: GENIUS! That did it. I was misusing CONCAT_WS. I read the description of its functionality, but I was locked into a behavior pattern trying to avoid the results of a NULL field. Thanks. Exactly what I needed.